# React Native - IOS( Drawer partially opened on Login)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

When I Login to the application drawer is partially opened, if I kill the app and reopen again drawer is fully closed. Not sure what is causing the issue.

```
 <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='HomeDrawerItem' screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, drawerPosition: 'right', drawerStyle: {width:"88%"}, drawerType: 'front' }}
```

Changing drawerType to 'back' is solving the issue, but its not the required design.
"@react-navigation/drawer": "6.5.4" //Latest version is also having the same issue

Comment: This sounds like an issue I had a couple of month. Try to use the ```useLegacyImplementation``` flag.

Comment: @MichaelBahl thank you , this resolved the issue , but could you explain what this is and why this resolved the issue

Comment: No, there might be an issue with the react-reanimated v2 implementation.
But I didn't take a deep dive to track down the issue.