# Apk showing white screen after running eas build

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, apk

I ran `eas build -p android --profile` preview and than i downloaded the apk.
When i click on my app it shows splash screen and after that i get a white screen, only the status bar has a bg color.

[this is my screen in the apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK8jm.png)

I use sdk version 49

This is my app.js:

```js
                       
import {StatusBar, Text} from "react-native";
import {useFonts} from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerToggleButton,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import FontAwesome5 from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import COLORS from "./constants/colors";
import Card from "./screens/Card";
import Settings from "./screens/Settings";

import {selected} from "./globalState";
import {useSnapshot} from "valtio";
import data from "./data.json";

export default function App() {
  const snap = useSnapshot(selected);
  const titleTexts = data[snap.lang];

  const retrieveLanguage = async () => {
    try {
      const storedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("language");
      if (storedLanguage !== null) {
        selected.lang = storedLanguage;
      } else {
        selected.lang = "0";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveLanguage();
  }, []);

  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Quick sand": require("./assets/fonts/Quicksand.ttf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    }
    prepare();
  }, []);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }

  StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(COLORS.mint);

  return (
    
      <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          overlayColor: COLORS.overlayColor,
          swipeEdgeWidth: 3250,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: COLORS.mint,
          },
          headerTitleContainerStyle: {
            marginLeft: 5,
            width: "100%",
            alignItems: "center",
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: "Quick sand",
            fontSize: 24.5,

            textDecorationLine: "underline",
            textShadowOffset: {width: 2, height: 2},
            textShadowRadius: 4,
            textShadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
          },
          headerLeft: () => ,
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {
            marginRight: 1,
            marginTop: 7,
          },
          headerRightContainerStyle: {
            display: "none",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="card"
          component={Card}
          options={{
            title: titleTexts.dateIdeaHeaderText,
            drawerIcon: ({focused}) => (
              <FontAwesome5
                name={"book"}
                size={focused ? 24 : 20}
                color={focused ? COLORS.iconFocused : COLORS.icon}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="settings"
          component={Settings}
          options={{
            title: titleTexts.settingsHeaderText,
            drawerIcon: ({focused}) => (
              <FontAwesome5
                name={"cogs"}
                size={focused ? 25 : 20}
                color={focused ? COLORS.iconFocused : COLORS.icon}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      
    
  );
}
```

I dont get any errors.
I tried to rebuild it multiple times but it didn't work.

Comment: Try using ```useLegacyImplementation``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76817139/react-native-ios-drawer-partially-opened-on-login#comment135424003_76817139

Comment: Unfortuately it has no impact. But i tried building the app only without the navigation and it worked. So i thing the nav is the problem

Comment: Without drawer navigation?

Comment: Yes i built the app only with on screen to test

Comment: Wow i now tried building it with bottom tabs and now when i tab on a tab i keeps closing